# (Vue) Inject variable into all components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a global status variable, `STATUS`, that I'd like to inject into essentially all of my Vue components, given so many of them have to test against the status of API calls.

Two questions:

1. Does this kind of go against a Vue paradigm, and I should find a different solution?
2. If not, what is the best way to do this (add to `window`, etc...)?

Comment: Does it need to be reactive or do you just need access to it?

Comment: Just access.  No reactivity.